# Automatically center vim search results

Tags: vim

When I do a search with vim or gvim, the resulting positioning of the cursor within the window is somewhat random, all too frequently landing on the last (or first) line in the window.  Search highlighting helps, but it's still cumbersome to have to look all around on the screen to find the cursor ... and a bit ironic, that after vim locates the next result in some megabytes-long log file, I have to use the ol' neocortex to isolate it from the last 4K or so.

I can *manually* get the effect I want by hitting 'zz' after every search, but would prefer to doctor up my _vimrc to make this happen automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center cursor position after search in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892498/center-cursor-position-after-search-in-vim)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Will this work for you ?

```
:nmap n nzz  
:nmap p pzz
```

Comment: figured it was probably about that easy. that's awesome. thanks!

Comment: Nice. For completeness, I'd also add the counterparts `:nmap N Nzz` and `:nmap P Pzz`.

Comment: Any reason for using `nmap` and not `nnoremap`? AFAIK you should always use the non-recursive mappings

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using this mapping fails to unfold the code like the normal `n` does. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MikeB I posted an answer that might help opening folds. So far it's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick with other commands too:

```
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
nnoremap <C-o> <C-o>zz
nnoremap <C-i> <C-i>zz
```

Answer (score 1):

I had been using the `nzz` mapping for some time until I discovered an option that works better for me. I was also annoyed by results being displayed on the first or last line on screen.

This option keeps the cursor (and therefore the current search result) 5 lines below/above the first/last line.

```
:set scrolloff=5
```

I prefer this because `nzz` is annoying in case you have many search results on one page and *each* `n` scrolls the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike-B pointed out, the accepted answer of doing

```
nmap n nzz
```

does not open folds.
As an alternative I propose the following. It is a bit hacky, but seems to work for me:

```
nmap nzvzz
```

and equivalent for the other motions, if you want. zv should open all folds till the current cursor position is visible.