# Center cursor position after search in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like Vim to place my cursor vertically in the middle of screen after search. I have achieved that for `*`, `#`, `n` and `N` commands with the following lines in my `vimrc`:

```
nmap * *zz
nmap # #zz
nmap n nzz
nmap N Nzz
```

My question is: How to map `/` and `?` the same way? In other words, I would like to position the cursor in the same way after some text has been found using the following commands:

```
/some-text-to-find-forward
?some-text-to-find-backward
```

Comment: The [vim-oblique plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-oblique) does that. But it has a lot of dependencies and sometimes creates lags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Threw away my initial answer as it was too much of a kludge.  Here's a much better solution.

```
function! CenterSearch()
  let cmdtype = getcmdtype()
  if cmdtype == '/' || cmdtype == '?'
    return "\<enter>zz"
  endif
  return "\<enter>"
endfunction

cnoremap <silent> <expr> <enter> CenterSearch()
```

The way this works is to remap <kbd>Enter</kbd> in command-line-mode to a custom expression.

The function performs the current search followed by <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> if the command-line is currently in a search.  Otherwise it just executes whatever command was being done.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very pretty, but

```
:nnoremap / :execute "normal! /\<lt>cr>zz"<c-left><right>
```

will get the job done. (Puts an `:execute "normal! /"` command on the commandline, then adds a `<cr>zz` to the end to it so that you automatically `zz` when you issue the command. The final `<c-left><right>` just steps into the search pattern at the right spot

Comment: Thank you! You are right: it's "not verry pretty" but works:) I've tried and put it into my vimrc but now I want to try Randy's solution that seems to be a little bit cleaner;)

Comment: His is the better version (cleaner and without as much a chance to mess up with a stray backspace...) and I'm very confused as to why I didn't think of it myself. Kudos to him.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Randy Morris but as a oneliner:

```
cnoremap <silent><expr> <enter> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) >= 0 ? '<enter>zz' : '<enter>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an excerpt from my `~/.vimrc` that improves the search behavior in `vim` by centering the search matches vertically when the `n`, `N`, `/` or `?` commands are used, but only if jumping from the current cursor position to the search match goes up or down more than 3/4 (75%) of the actual window height.  This helps a lot with the navigation through the edited file while searching, by preserving the context.

```
" Center the window vertically at the last search match if the search ends up
" scrolling the window up or down at least 75% (3/4) of the actual window height,
" which preserves the context and makes search navigation much easier
"
function! CenterSearch(command = v:null)
  set lazyredraw
  if a:command isnot v:null
    let winstartold = line("w0")
    let winendold   = line("w$")
    try
      execute "normal! " .. a:command
    catch
      echohl ErrorMsg
      echo substitute(v:exception, "^Vim(.*):", "", "")
      echohl NONE
    endtry
  else
    let winstartold = s:winstartold
    let winendold   = s:winendold
  endif
  let winstartnew = line("w0")
  let winendnew   = line("w$")
  let winframe    = float2nr(winheight(0) * (1.0 - 0.75))
  if (winendnew - winstartnew + 1 > 0 && winendold - winstartold + 1 > 0)
  \  && ((winstartnew < winstartold && winendnew < winendold
  \       && winendnew <= winstartold + winframe)
  \      || (winstartnew > winstartold && winendnew > winendold
  \          && winstartnew >= winendold - winframe))
    execute "normal zz"
  endif
  redraw
  set nolazyredraw
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> n :call CenterSearch("n")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> N :call CenterSearch("N")<CR>

" Execute the search as usual, while remembering the resulting window position
" and possibly centering the window vertically at the resulting match
"
function! ExecuteSearch()
  let cmdtype = getcmdtype()
  if cmdtype ==# "/" || cmdtype ==# "?"
    let s:winstartold = line("w0")
    let s:winendold   = line("w$")
    return "\<CR>\<Esc>:call CenterSearch()\<CR>"
  endif
  return "\<CR>"
endfunction

cnoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> ExecuteSearch()
```

I know, this is a sizable chunk of vimscript code, but it also does quite a lot, which includes eliminating the screen flickering that may happen quite often as a result of the function scrolling the window.

I find this approach much more useful than just having the search matches always centered vertically, which doesn't preserve the context and, as a result, often makes the navigation through the edited file cumbersome.

I'd highly suggest that you also configure `vim` to keep a minimal number of screen lines above and below the cursor, to preserve even more context of the edited file, by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set scrolloff=3
```

See also [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42798/48490), which may provide some additional comfort in `vim`.